# How to use Connection pool in Multi Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, connection-pooling

I am using multiple threads to insert millions of records into the database.
I'm using 3 classes.

**GetConnection**:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import LoadConfig;
public class DBCP {
    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("DBCP");
    private Connection conn;
    public static Connection getOracleConnection() throws SQLException,
         ClassNotFoundException {
     String hostName = LoadConfig.Getconfig("hostName");
     String sid = LoadConfig.Getconfig("sid");
     String userName = LoadConfig.Getconfig("userName");
     String password = LoadConfig.Getconfig("password");

     return getOracleConnection(hostName, sid, userName, password);
 }

    private static Connection getOracleConnection(String hostName, String sid, String userName, String password) 
            throws SQLException {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        try 
        {
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + hostName + ":1521:" + sid);
            dataSource.setUsername(userName);
            dataSource.setPassword(password);
            dataSource.setMaxTotal(300);
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            log.error("SQLException"+ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Read Text**:

```
    public class Readtxt implements Runnable{
    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("ReadFile");
    File file = new File(path);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
          Connection conn = data.getOracleConnection() 
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()))) {
                String line;
                int i=0;
                log.info("Start read and update file: " + fileName);
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    Runnable Insert = new InsertDT(conn, line);
                    executor.execute(Insert);
                }
                log.info("Finish reading: " + fileName);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.fatal("ReadFile IOException: " + ex);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.fatal("Connect Error: " + ex);
        } 
    }
}
```

and **Insert class**:

```
public class InsertDT implements Runnable{
    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("InsertDT");
    private String line
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement statement;
    public InsertDT(Connection _conn, String _line){
            this.conn = _conn;
            this.line = _line;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            try {
                this.statement = conn.prepareCall("{ Call Produce  (?,?)}");
                statement.setString("Data", line);
                statement.executeUpdate();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            } 
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            log.error(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

But the project takes a lot of time to insert records into the dataase. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: try batch insert instead of inserting one at a time

Answer (score 1):

First of all for each read thread you are building `datasource`.

```
Connection conn = data.getOracleConnection()
```

It's good to have singleton datasource. Which you will build during application start up and use it every time when you need it from your `Factory` implementation.

Second you are sharing the same `connection` which you got from `datasource`.

```
Runnable Insert = new InsertDT(conn, line);
```

It's best to assign separate `connection` for each `thread`. So every time you refer to the same `datasource` and get a new `connection` and give it to each thread to work with it.

More over it doesn't really matter how big is your thread pool and how many concurrent thread you have assigned; all that matters is the `CPU core`.